# Looking for a 3 button selector set of buttons that can be panel mounted

Tags: switching, panel-mounting

I've implemented tactile button solutions using a PCBA and microcontroller, but I would like to find an off the shelf module that has three buttons that allows the user to select one of three inputs.  These inputs would go to a microcontroller, but I am trying to avoid another PCBA.  My goal is to find something that can be placed under sheet metal such that only the three buttons tops are accessible by the user. I've spent a lot of time searching, but I think I just don't know what to call these things as I search.  Again off the shelf option here; I know what to do if I had to design my own PCBA here, trying to avoid that cycle, for this simple function.

Of any of the options (button stays pressed, button lights, etc.), I have no preference - might just be cost tradeoffs.

Thanks.

Comment: You have no specs  !  cost , performance, size.  They will be called momentary SPST button switches. Simple https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=momentary+SPST+button+switches&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover  with panel mount  . The secret is to define adjectives and nouns https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=momentary%20SPST%20button%20switches%20budget%20%22panel%20mount%22&qs=n&form=QBIR&sp=-1&pq=momentary%20spst%20button%20switches%20budget%20%22panel%20mount%22&sc=0-51&cvid=F42396DA6E3F4306AD14F6E2221D8DD6&first=1&tsc=ImageBasicHover  after searching and looking at the description

Comment: Nice ones are $50, Cheap ones are $2 https://www.ebay.com/itm/12x12mm-Momentary-Tactile-Push-Button-Switch-PCB-Mounted-SPST-/251779585322

Comment: you are really looking for one button ... buy three when you find it

Comment: May be you will get more respondents interested if you provide a bit of a background into what type of use these switches will see. For instance, what is the temperature of the housing? Is humidity a factor? Do you have a slot in the housing (what size) for this switch already? How much use will it see? Will users operate these switches with greasy hands? etc. I would say that this post requires some elaboration yet. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I did not provide more info, because I am not looking for help to find the exact specific part - it's more of asking for help on nomenclature. Figured this was an easy question to the right person.  These links have been helpful (Tony), I've used these switches before, but what I was hoping to find was an off the shelf module that has the pulldowns, wiring, etc.

Comment: Start eg [here](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/pushbutton-switches/199?s=N4IgTCBcDaIA4FcDOALARggLpg9gOyRAF0BfIA) and [here](https://www.digikey.co.nz/en/products/filter/configurable-switch-components-body/206?s=N4IgTCBcDaIA4FcDOALARggLpg9gOyRAF0BfIA) and use the filters to zero in on what may be suitable. Also Mouser and others.

Comment: Jeff your requirements could be more precisely defined with limits , like cost size , current , colour, shape, interface.. or anything that really matters. There's a million buttons out there

Answer (score 0):

This is not the shopping channel but I think you want, "budget, panel-mount momentary button-switches for logic signals."

The problem is they must be gold plated < 2A switches and cheap switches will oxidize and quickly fail until you add de-wetting caps across them to burn off the oxidation.  I have used 22 uF caps in the past successfully to de-wet and solve this problem with the pull R to V+.  The other problem is eBay-type parts have no specs or quality guarantee.

[image]

If you need high quality, you need to learn about the causes of part-failures and develop a vocabulary for quality details, MTBF and switch types. https://www.codrey.com/electronics/types-of-switches-in-electronics/